# Xcode 7 - Swift TODO comments

Tags: swift, xcode, comments, xcode7, todo

Using Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0, I'm trying to use TODO comments like I would in Visual Studio with C#. I've found sites suggesting

```
// MARK: comment here
// TODO: comment here
// FIXME: comment here
```

but none of these seem to work. I'm checking the function hierarchy where it looks like the comments should appear afterwards, and it never updates.

This is what I'm expecting:

[image: A TODO: comment showing up in Xcode's intellisense]

How can I get these comments to show up in Xcode's intellisense?

Comment: Didn't Microsoft patent highlighting todo comments in lists? http://www.cnet.com/uk/news/microsoft-checks-off-patent-win/

Comment: I didn't know that actually, but it might be the sorting of comments into a list that's patented. Chonch's response shows how it looks in Xcode.

Answer (score 8):

Adding code annotation to the jump bar

> You can add useful information, such as to-dos, bug-fix reminders, and
>   section headings to the jump bar symbol pop-up menu by annotating your
>   code in the source editor.
>
> Add a to-do item: Insert a comment with the prefix TODO:.
>
> For example:
>
> // TODO: [your to-do item].
>
> Add a bug fix reminder: Insert a comment with the prefix FIXME:.
>
> For example:
>
> // FIXME: [your bug fix reminder].
>
> Add a heading: Insert a comment with the prefix MARK:.
>
> For example:
>
> // MARK: [your section heading].
>
> Add a separator line: To add a separator above an annotation, add a
>   hyphen (-) before the comment portion of the annotation.
>
> For example:
>
> // MARK: - [your content]. To add a separator below an
>   annotation, add a hyphen (-) after the comment portion of the
>   annotation.
>
> For example:
>
> // MARK: [your content] -.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev86a148f73

Answer (score 2):

Just pasting your comments code in Xcode 7 with Swift 2.0 seems to work. It looks like this:[image]

Comment: It has to be something on my end then. I'm using 7.0.1. I copied and pasted my above comments, both inside and outside of a function, and I don't see them showing up under AppDelegate or ViewController's hierarchy. I appreciate the feedback!